# Do Drow add their proficiency bonus to hit along with their racial trait bonus for short swords and hand crossbows?

Tags: dnd-5e, drow

A drow has +4 to hit and d6+2 damage with both a short sword and a hand crossbow. At first level they also have +2 proficiency bonus to hit. Does that give them (disregarding any ability bonuses) +6 to hit with a short sword and hand crossbow?

Comment: You mean the Drow from the Monster Manual, right?

Answer (score 15):

### The stat block already includes the +2 from proficiency.

Both the shortsword and the hand crossbow use dexterity to calculate the attack bonus. As you can see in the stat block, the drow has a +2 dexterity bonus. Therefore, its +4 to hit accounts for the +2 from dexterity and the +2 from proficiency.

Answer (score -2):

No, it just means that they have proficiency on attacks made with those weapons, proficiency does not stack. Otherwise someone could just take the **Weapons Master** feat 3 times and have like a +26 to hit at some point. But if you're talking about the actual Drow in the MM then it's already included in the attack bonus.